# Pattern match parameters to function calls Python?

Tags: python, types, pattern-matching

I'm writing a python function that calls a function based on a parameter it takes. It looks something like this:

```
def match(parameter):
  if parameter == 'fun1':
    fun1()
  elif parameter == 'fun2':
    fun2()
  elif parameter == 'fun3':
    fun3()
```

All those functions being called are then defined below the `match` function. Is there a more efficient way to organize the `match` function? I can't find anything about pattern matching with functions, but could a data structure of some sort work?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary which stores the mapping between the function and the parameter value to call it.

For example:

```
def fun1():
    print("I am fun1")


def fun2():
    print("I am fun2")

funcs_mapping = {"fun1":fun1, "fun2":fun2}

def match(parameter):
  if parameter in funcs_mapping:
      funcs_mapping[parameter]()
```

Comment: different functions may have different arguments

Comment: How do you know that @abhinonymous

Comment: @abhinonymous Then you can wrap each function in a `lambda` or a `partial` before storing it in the dictionary (wait, you're not the OP).

Comment: @abhinonymous According to OP's question, the functions don't receive any params.

Comment: One difference between this code and OPs is how it handles unknown keys. The OP just returns None, this will raise an exception.

Comment: @MarkMeyer you are right! I've updated my solution. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: All these functions luckily are uniform, taking the same two parameters and all returning a list